# How to modify the value of a variable inside a variable from another script, in the current script

Tags: bash, unix

I have two bash scripts `a.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
d="printing from a.sh ${c}"
export d
```

and `b.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
c="yourtab"
echo ${d}
```

I am running `b.sh` by sourcing `a.sh`

```
source a.sh && sh b.sh
```

below is he output

```
printing from a.sh
```

but I want the output to be as below

```
printing from a.sh yourtab
```

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Since I was asked why I want to do this, I would like to give the actual scenario why I want to do this. Below is the scenario and the corresponding code.

I have an email function `email()` defined in `esh.sh` existing in folder mails, which takes values eto, ecc, esub.

I create variables mto, mcc, msub in `env.sh`

I have a `mains.sh`, where I am calling `email` function

`env.sh` looks like below

```
source mails/esh.sh
export -f email

export MTO="a@exp.com"
export MCC="b@exp.com"
export MSUB="this is the subject for running ${job} today"
```

`mains.sh` looks like below

```
job="First Job"

eto=${MTO}
ecc=${MCC}
esub=${MSUB}

email -t eto -c ecc -s esub
```

I run the `mains.sh` after sourcing `env.sh` as below

```
source env.sh && sh mains.sh
```

When I run the above code, I am getting the subject as `this is the subject for running  today`

But I want the subject to be `this is the subject for running First Job today`

Hope I made it clear now.

Comment: The value of `d` is assigned when `a.sh` is executed, so it will use the value of `c` *at this time*. Please [edit] your question and explain what you want to achieve with this code. Defining a function in `a.sh` and calling the function in `b.sh` might solve your problem.

Comment: Technically, you could do  a`d=' printing from a.sh ${c}'` and then in b.sh a `eval "$d"`, but I don't see why you would like to want this behaviour. This smells like misusing a feature for something it was not intended for.

Comment: off topic: I think you want to change `email -t eto -c ecc -s esub` into `email -t "$eto" -c "$ecc" -s "$esub"`

Comment: @user1934428: Anytime you find yourself reaching for the `eval` command it is a near certainty there are problems with the design of the program/solution. Using `eval` is a huge red flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$ cat a
#!/bin/bash
d="printing from a.sh %s"
export d

$ cat b
#!/bin/bash
c="yourtab"
printf "$d" "$c"
```

result

```
$ . a; ./b
printing from a.sh yourtab
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `d` is assigned when the line `d="printing from a.sh ${c}"` is executed, i.e. when you run `a.sh`, so it will use the value of `c` *at this time*.

If you later set or modify the value of `c`, the value of `d` will not change.

You could achieve the requested output with a function.

file `a.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

message1()
{
    echo "printing from a.sh ${c}"
}

# or

message2()
{
    echo "printing from a.sh $*"
}

export -f message1 message2
```

and `b.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

c="yourtab"
message1

# or

message2 foo bar baz
```

Result:

```
source a.sh && ./b.sh
printing from a.sh yourtab
printing from a.sh foo bar baz
```

Note that exporting functions is a bash extension.